# Using jQuery to calculate offset in an absolutely positioned container

Tags: jquery, scroll, offset

All of my content is within an absolute container, `#content`, which is 100% width and height. So when scrolling, we are scrolling through the container, not the body.

I am trying to caclulate the offset of a series of sections within the page like so:

```
$('.advance').on("click", function(){
     var nextSection = $(this).parent('.section').next('.section');

     var nextDistanceTop = nextSection.offset().top - 25;

     $("#content").animate({ scrollTop: nextDistanceTop });
});
```

Because the container is absolutely positioned, the offset().top is giving me the offset from the top of the viewport. I need to calculate the offset relative to the top of the screen/header, or the scroll position. Any other workarounds to accomplish this?

Here is an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/pkxDY/6/

Comment: What about creating a demo on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: OK I will put one together

Comment: Here is is: http://jsfiddle.net/pkxDY/6/

Comment: does $("body").scrollTop() work?  I think you need to add that to the absolute positioned element's offset().top to get how far down the element appears

Comment: That wouldnt be calculating the sections offset from the top, can you fork a fiddle to show your idea by chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use own jQuery [scrollTop](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop) method:

```
$('.advance').on("click", function(){
   var nextSection = $(this).parent().next();
   var nextDistanceTop = nextSection.offset().top + $("#content").scrollTop();
   $("#content").animate({ scrollTop: nextDistanceTop });
});
```